# How to get latest version of an image from artifact registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

is there a command (gcloud) that return the latest fully qualified name of an image from Artifact registry

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```sh
PROJECT=
REGION=
REPO=
IMAGE=

gcloud artifacts docker images list \
${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REPO} \
--filter="package=${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REPO}/${IMAGE}" \
--sort-by="~UPDATE_TIME" \
--limit=1 \
--format="value(format("{0}@{1}",package,version))"
```

Because:

1. Filters the list for a specific image
2. Sorts the results descending (`~`) by `UPDATE_TIME`<sup>1</sup>
3. Only takes 1 value i.e. the most recent
4. Outputs the results as `{package}@{version}`

> <sup>1</sup> -- Curiously, `--sort-by` uses the output (!) field name not the underlying type (surfaced by e.g. `--format=json` or `--format=yaml`) name.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to the previous answer, I use it to remove the tag "latest" of my last pushed artifact. I then add it when I push another. Leaving here if anyone interested.

Doc : https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/manage-images#tag

**Remove tag :**

```
gcloud artifacts docker tags delete \
$(gcloud artifacts docker images list ${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/\
${PROJECT}/${REPO}/${IMAGE}/\ 
--filter="package=${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REPO}/${IMAGE}"\
 --sort-by="~UPDATE_TIME" --limit=1 --format="value(format("{0}",package))"):latest
```

**Add tag:**

```
gcloud artifacts docker tags add \
$(gcloud artifacts docker images list \
${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REPO}/${IMAGE}/ \
--filter="package=${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REPO}/${IMAGE}" \
--sort-by="~UPDATE_TIME" --limit=1 \
--format="value(format("{0}@{1}",package,version))") \
$(gcloud artifacts docker images list \
${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REPO}/${IMAGE}/ \
--filter="package=${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REPO}/${IMAGE}" \
--sort-by="~UPDATE_TIME" --limit=1 \
--format="value(format("{0}",package))"):latest
```